# create tree from 2d array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tree

we are trying to create a tree from 2d array and wants to check if given nodes exist in that tree or not.

For example
Suppose we have these array

```
links = [[0,3],[2,4],[8,5],[9,1],[5,2],[1,5]]
check = [[7,6],[1,2],[8,3],[8,9]]
```

must give result

```
 [false,true,false,true]
```

Because

```
1 and 2 are connected via 5 (1-5-2)
8 and 9 are connected via 5 and 1 (8-5-1-9)
```

According to us, Our logic is 1-5-2 ([5,2],[1,5]) and 8-5-1-9 ([8,5],[9,1],[1,5]) is tree which is connected to each other in array. If we can create tree like this then we can solve this problem.

I wrote some code for tree structure but its not giving correct result.

```
var links = [[0,3],[2,4],[8,5],[9,1],[5,2],[1,5]];
var check = [[7,6],[1,2],[8,3],[8,9]];

console.log(links.join(",").split(","));


var p, temp = {};
var test={};
var result={};

for (var i=links.join(",").split(",").length; i--; ) {
    p = links.join(",").split(",")[i];
    temp[p] = (p in temp) ? temp[p]+1 : 1;
}

for(key in temp){
    if(temp[key]>1){
        test[key]=temp[key];
        console.log("now greater then 1");
      }
}
console.log(test);

for (var index = 0, len = links.length; index < len; index++) {
  //  console.log(links[index]);
  for(key in test){
  console.log(key +"----"+links[index]);
    if(key in links[index]){
        console.log(links[index]);
    }else{
        console.log("in else");
    }
  }
}
console.log(temp);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmLL4rvw/4/)

Comment: How is this a tree? Isn't that just a graph?

Comment: Or is it the data structure for a graph, but there's a precondition that there are no loops, so you can ignore loops in you code?

Comment: Yes, this is a data structure type, But i don't think its a graph. Because some node is related to others and we need to find those.

Comment: ok, so you do not know what a graph is and you probably do not even know what tree is. Define exactly what kind of data you have. I assime it is directed (as in [1,5] is not the same as [5,1]) and there are no loops. What's strange is that there is not just one tree. It looks like there can be many trees in the graph that are not interconnected.   
So figure out what you actually have and what you need to do. Then learn what you need to know to solve the problem. Nobody here will do your homework for you.

Comment: And you are not even using jquery. Remove that from the title and the tags. And this is a 2d array, but not what people would expect when you say it's a tree. It's really a list of pairs, which represent edges.

Comment: Graph:-Two-dimensional drawing showing a relationship (usually between two set of numbers) by means of a line, curve, a series of bars, or other symbols. Tree:-  tree is a widely used abstract data type (ADT)—or data structure implementing this ADT—that simulates a hierarchical tree structure, with a root value and subtrees of children with a parent node, represented as a set of linked nodes.

Thats why i think its a tree not graph.

Comment: But we can use jquery.

Comment: "usually between two set of numbers" No, that would be a mapping. A graph is the most basic data structure. Anything else is a specialisation of a graph.  You need to learn these basics first.
What you have is not a tree. Where is the root? Where is anything that makes sure there is a hierarchical structure? The nodes aren't even interconnected. If they were you'd get true for all input. Your question makes no sense.   
You do not use jquery here and it is not relevant for the question, so remove it already. Or wait until some admin flags or even deletes your question. That's up to you.